# How to Create A Multidimensional Record in Ember

Tags: ember.js, multidimensional-array

I'm relatively new with Ember.

I'm trying to save a multidimensional record so that I can easily have observables set to appropriately populate some select menus.

I've tried using square brackets, circle brackets, and dot notation to try to save the record, but I can't figure out how to set it up properly.

Here's what I was trying

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    publishCity: function() {
      var newCity = this.store.createRecord('city', {
         city.country: this.get('country'),
         city.province: this.get('province'),
         city.city : this.get('city'),
      });
      newCity.save();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you call this "multi-dimensional'? Anyway, this is not even valid JS. Start by changing `model.country: ...` to `country: ...`. Or, more simply, `this.store.createRecord('city, this.getProperties('country', 'province', 'city'))`.

Comment: Well I want to avoid having to create a new model for each level (city, province/state, country). So when a user selects 'Canada' from a dropdown, then the provinces populate in the next dropdown, and same for the cities after that.. So my assumption was that using a multi dimensional array would be the easiest thing.

Comment: And I realize the JS wasn't valid, but I was just trying to illustrate generally what I was trying to achieve.